# Loading more records than actual in HIve

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

While inserting from Hive table to HIve table, It is loading more records that actual records. Can anyone help in this weird behaviour of Hive ?

My query would be looking like this:

```
insert overwrite table_a
    select col1,col2,col3,... from table_b;
```

My table_b consists of 6405465 records.

After inserting from table_b to table_a, i found total records in table_a are 6406565.

Can any one please help here ?

Comment: are they stored differently? maybe you have `table_a` line delimiters in some of the data

Comment: Yes, table_b is normal text table. where as table_a is partitioned text table. And both the tables are having line delimeted by '\n', feilds delimeted by '\t'

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39914232/2700344  Check if you are using stats for count(*) computation

Comment: After making hive.compute.query.using.stats=false it is showing the same count of records. But can you explain why it is happened before with ture option ?

Comment: Explained. See my answer please.

Answer (score 3):

If `hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;` then optimizer is using statistics for query calculation instead of querying table data. This is much faster because metastore is a fast database like MySQL and does not require map-reduce. But statistics can be not fresh (stale) if the table was loaded not using INSERT OVERWRITE or configuration parameter `hive.stats.autogather` responsible for statistics auto gathering was set to false. Also statistics will be not fresh after loading files or after using third-party tools. It's because files was never analyzed, statistics in metastore is not fresh, if you have put new files, nobody knows about how the data was changed. Also after sqoop loading, etc. So, it's a good practice to gather statistics for table or partition after loading using 'ANALYZE TABLE ... COMPUTE STATISTICS'.

In case it's impossible to gather statistics automatically (works for INSERT OVERWRITE) or by running `ANALYZE` statement then better to switch off `hive.compute.query.using.stats` parameter. Hive will query data instead of using statistics.

See this for reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-StatisticsinHive